# Отправка base64 методом POST на веб сервер на Java?

Tags: java, post, веб-сервер, base64

Не получается отправить правильно base64 методом POST на вебсервер, где то читал что проблема в encoding или UTF-8, но не могу найти правильную информацию. (через Postman все работает) но в Java нет

Код на Java:

```
String base64encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(stringXml.getBytes());

        System.out.println(base64encodedString);

        // POST
        // METHOD-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        String url = "http://192.168.1.9/udr/IhdMeta/services/ihd.asmx";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // add reuqest header con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String urlParameters = "base64=" + base64encodedString + "&AlgId=" + MetaAlg.getString("id") + "&rec=SC"; // Send
                                                                                                                    // post
                                                                                                                    // request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response2 = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response2.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(response2.toString());
```

результат:

```
Sending 'POST' request to URL : 
http://192.168.1.9/udr/IhdMeta/services/ihd.asmx
Response Code : 200
{"status":0,"message":"Недопустимая длина строки или массива знаков Base-64."}
```

Comment: А что если wr.writeBytes(urlParameters) заменить на wr.writeBytes(urlParameters.getBytes())?

Comment: @OlegA благодарю за ваш ответ, но я вчера решил эту проблему тем, что изменил строчку с UTF-8 __base64encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(base64encodedString, "UTF-8")__